# WooCommerce line_total and line_subtotal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is there any way to change the `line_total` and `line_subtotal` in WooCommerce once an order is in add to cart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There two hook for **check out page** where you can modify line total and line sub total.
**woocommerce_calculate_totals**

```
function action_woocommerce_calculate_totals( $fee ) { 
   // add your logic
   }; 

// add the action
 add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals','action_woocommerce_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```

**woocommerce_cart_subtotal**

```
   function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $array, $int, $int ) { 
     // implement your logic 
     return $array; 
    }; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You forget the single quote in add_action(woocommerce_calculate_totals','action_woocommerce_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );

Comment: Ash let me clear you my need. I have a custom product type called weight product in which i use pricing table . i can display a input field above the add to cart button in which user can add quantity and below price will be calculated now i want to use this price for sell my . note product with no regular and sale price i use woocommerce_get_price filter to  show product add to cart button on single page. kindly help in this regard

Comment: can you update your question with piece of your code as well?